# Try / Except does not work on UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' when reading json

Tags: python, json

I want to read one json file with python. JSON file contains emojis so I get the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 96-96: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk
```

I want to skip the rows that has emoji, to continue the loop without that row. I have tried to use try except statement but I still get the same error:
I have used:

```
try:
    url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/" + str(postid) + "/comments?" + token_id  # api link
    r = requests.get(url) #getting the data
    json_comment = r.json() # converting to json

    if json_comment.get("data") != []:
        json_comment = json_comment["data"][0]["text"] #taking values from json

        list_of_rows.append([client_id, postid, json_comment]) #ubacujem komentare u listu

except:
    continue
```

But the error is the same. I have tried to do `except UnicodeEncodeError: continue` and `except UnicodeEncodeError: pass` but the error is the same

Comment: which line of code gives error. In error I see text "in Tk" - do you use "Tkitner" ? maybe you have problem with Tkinter which can't display it.

Comment: Maybe you can try getting a string `resp_str = r.text` first, and then using the `json` module to interpret it from there? (perhaps after filtering out the emoji, e.g. by doing `json.loads(ascii(r.text))`?

Comment: @furas I do not use IDLE that came out with Python 3. instalation. this code is not for gui development

Comment: you don't have to use IDLE but other tools which can use tkinter - turtle, matplotlib, etc. ` not supported in Tk` definitly means problem with Tkinter. In full error (Traceback) you should see line which makes problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```py
try:
    #your code here

#You can use
except UnicodeEncodeError as e:
    pass
#or
except Exception as e:
    pass
```